# What happens to pixels when an image is resized?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, filter

I have this original image of size 800 x 600px

[image]

What I have to do is to resize the image to 625 x 480px and filter all the land areas. I have found that the BGR values of the land part is (95,155,212). This is the code I used to filter all the and areas:

```
image[np.where((image == [95,155,212]).all(axis = 2))] = [0,0,0]
```

If I resize first, then filter, here is the output:

[image]

If I filter first then resize, I get my desired output:

[image]

So my first question is what happened to the image's pixels when it is resized?

I have this original image of size 712 x 480px

[image]

When I applied filtering to remove the land area, I get an output like the second image from the top. 2nd question, is there any way for me to fix this problem?

Comment: What are you using to resize the image? Are you using `cv2.resize`?  If you are, then bilinear interpolation is performed by default to interpolate the pixels when resizing the image.  However, I don't quite understand what your question is.  What exactly is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Yup I used `cv2.resize`. My problem is I am unable to apply thorough filtering of the land area out of the last image, and the output I get always has the linings around these filtered land areas (same problem as the second image from the top)

Comment: Ah well that makes sense.  The reason why is because the lining/grid has a different colour than what you're trying to zero out.  So your objective is to remove the land masses (orange areas) out of the image, in addition to those linings that intersect the masses?

Comment: Yes I am stuck there. Seems to me that only for bigger images then my 1-line filter works. Also, my aim is to filter all the land, and since there are other details in the image that has the same colour as the land, I tried to minimize the BGR range to be filtered, so I picked the most common values which is `(95,155,212)` but it results in a lot of linings left

Comment: Showing your exact `resize` code could help too.  Can you update your post to reflect this?  I'm assuming you want the water bodies to be maintained as well?

Comment: The image I am having problem with does not need any resize :/

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.... so you want to approach this without doing resize at all?

Comment: What I did was apply filtering directly as I'm not sure if any resizing would help :/ and the water bodies should also be maintained

Comment: Since when I tried filtering on bigger images (like the first image) there was no lining problem, I tried making the last image bigger then filter and resize back but the linings are still there

Answer (score 2):

most likely the resizing changes the border colors to something between land color and black outline.

This screws up your filter because you need higher ranges for land color and also the border line color (Black) can have color artifacts. These artifact are what is left after filtering in your example. If you pick their colors they should be outside your selected range.

**How to repair?**

1. **use nearest neighbor resizing**

   this will left the colors as are but the resized image is not as pretty ...
2. **change filters to handle close colors not just range of color**

   so change to something like flood fill and fill all pixels that do not differ too much from each other. You need 2 thresholds for this:

   - absolute (is the color range total big one)
   - relative (is the max change of neighboring pixels small one)

   now just recolor the resized image or change the filter function to this ...

Answer (score 0):

**Image sizes onscreen and in print**

The size of an image when you view it onscreen is different from its size when you print it. If you understand these differences, you can develop a better understanding of which settings to change when you resize an image.

**Screen size**

The screen resolution of your monitor is the number of pixels it can display. For example, a monitor with a screen resolution of 640 x 480 pixels displays 640 pixels for the width and 480 pixels for the height. There are several different screen resolutions you can use, and the physical size of the monitor screen usually determines the resolutions available. For example, large monitors typically display higher resolutions than small monitors because they have more pixels.

**Image size onscreen**

Images are of a fixed pixel size when they appear on your monitor. Your screen resolution determines how large the image appears onscreen. A monitor set to 640 x 480 pixels displays fewer pixels than a monitor displaying 1024 x 768 pixels. Therefore, each of the pixel on the 640 x 480 pixel monitor is larger than each pixel displayed on the 1024 x 768 pixel monitor.

A 100 x 100-pixel image uses about one-sixth of the screen at 640 x 480, but it takes up only about one-tenth of the screen at 1024 x 768. Therefore, the image looks smaller at 1024 x 768 pixels than at 640 x 480 pixels

**The Following Parameters change when you resize an image**
Pixel dimensions: The width and height of the image.
Image size :
Document size: Physical size of the image when printed, including a width and height.
Image resolution when printed: This value appears in pixels per inch or pixels per centimeter.

In Photoshop the physical size, resolution, and pixel dimensions of an image are calculated as follows:

1. Physical size = resolution x pixel dimensions
2. Resolution = physical size / pixel dimensions
3. Pixel dimensions = physical size / resolution

For more info on this you can check [Adobe's Document on Image resizing](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/advanced-cropping-resizing-resampling-photoshop.html)